# Merge pairs that share common elements overall, but not directly

Tags: r

I have a dataframe listing pairs such as:

```
groupA  groupB
7       57
7       93
93      203
203     301
301     407
383     567
...     ...
```

For example, 7 and 93 are connected to 301 and 407 by 203.

My desired output is something like:

```
[1] 7 57 93 203 301 407
[2] 383 567
...
```

When I started coding the solution in `R`, I began to think it should be solved with recursion (which I'm terrible at). The problem reminds me of a "six degrees of separation" kind of thing. Either way, I thought it would be much easier than it turned out.

I've stumbled across a few solutions in other languages but wondered if anyone had dealt with something like this in R.

Humble thanks to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you want connected components in a directed graph.
If `df1` is your data frame with "connections":

```
library(igraph)
g1 <- graph.data.frame(df1, directed = TRUE)
```

Function `clusters` will find all connected components:

```
cl1 <- clusters(g1)
```

Format the results:

```
tbl1 <- cbind( V(g1)$name, cl1$membership )
split(tbl1[,1], tbl1[,2])

# $`1`
# [1] "7"   "93"  "203" "301" "57"  "407"
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "383" "567"
```